# Variable height div undesirably changing size on hover because of border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There are two conditions:

- The div (and the divs inside) must have a variable height.
- The divs inside must add a border on hover over them.

There is a problem:

The border of the hover adds height to the div, therefore making undesirable height changes.

How to overcome this without changing the variable height to fixed height??

Answer (score 4):

Try applying `border-box` to all the elements:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution than what I posted!

Answer (score 1):

Transition not the `border` itself but the `border-color` property from transparent to the desired value. The point is that the border is defined along with its border-width by default with `border-color: transparent`, so on hover only the changing colour produces the effect of the border appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 divs.  Place a new `div` in your current `div` and set the border to the new `div` and set its height to 100%.

Example: https://codepen.io/danieldilly/pen/brbzbZ

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can do this.

1. Leave it as is (No!)
2. Create a `transparent` border that matches the `:hover` border.
3. Use [Use box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Examine the snippet below to see what works best for you.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.one {
  /* ...Nothing here...move along...*/
}

.two {
  border: 2px solid transparent
}

.three {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="one">default</div>
<div class="two">transparent</div>
<div class="three">box-sizing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline) CSS property. It has the same syntax as `border` and excellent cross-browser support (IE8+). Demo:

```css
.inner:hover {
  outline: 5px solid red;
}

/* just styles for demo */
.inner {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  Some outer div
  <div class="inner">
    Some inner div
  </div>
  Some outer div
</div>
```